# N-ary decision tree with categorical features

Tags: classification, cart, decision-theory

I want to build an n-ary decision tree with categorical features.
I am using ordinary ID3 algorithm to build a tree.

Lets take the next dataset as a training dataset for building a decision tree:

| dors | age | cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 0 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 |
| 3 | 5 | 0 |
| 3 | 6 | 1 |

A decision tree will look as such:

[image: decision tree]

Lets say now in test or prod time, an example comes with features `dors=3 age=4` our tree cannot classify this example even though it has seen examples where `doors=3` and examples where `age=4`.
My implementation throws an error that value is missing and sklearn implementations of decision trees are always binary trees.
Overall it cannot be expected that we covered all possible combinations in training set so there could always be examples in test set with unique combination of feature values which our tree cannot classify.
How can this problem be solved and what are some solutions for solving it?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/199587/categorical-variable-in-training-set-does-not-capture-all-cases is related to the issue of categorical values not seen during training

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model naturally can't have learned anything about such an instance, so you have to make some sort of assumption if you don't want to just give up like your current implementation.  One that comes to mind is to treat `age` as missing at the second node; there are several ways to handle missing values in a tree model, at either training or prediction time, see [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/96458/232706).  Since this particular use-case is only at prediction, I think either the weighted distribution or surrogate methods are most likely to be useful.  The latter doesn't work in your small example (there are no other features to act as surrogate), but if there were other features that could serve as a surrogate, it seems likely to produce better results than simply dividing the sample across children.

Comment: This did open up a few possibilities for a solution. I will look deeper into this. Does this mean that my problem is is practically equivalent to "missing values" problem? Is there another way to fight this?

Comment: @dzi I think there's room for solutions that don't mimic missing value treatments, but I'm not aware of any.